# Binary image from API, convert and save path

Tags: php, laravel, image, binary-image

Im receiving a binary image from an API ([Line API](https://developers.line.biz/en/reference/messaging-api/#get-content))

```
// if status 200
if ($response->isSucceeded()) {
    // get binary image from api
    $binary = $response->getRawBody();
    // convert to base64?
    $imageData = base64_encode($binary);
    // what do i do here?
}
```

After receiving it, I want to save the image in my public folder and save the path in my database.
There were several answers on SO that I thought could work like using intervention/image but I could not manage to fix this. Ive also found a comment saying this cant be done. Can someone give me a hint how I could do this. Or if this is even possible?

Thank you.

Comment: You probably should save the file?

Comment: I should save the binary data in a file and use the file to display images in html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Laravel, then you can use `Storage` facade to help you write the content into `private` storage or `public` storage.
If the image already on binary, just put/write as is, as binary.

Based on the docs, you can store the image as example :

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
// ..... controller
// if status 200
if ($response->isSucceeded()) {
    // get binary image from api
    $binary = $response->getRawBody();
    Storage::disk("public")->put("/img/some-image.jpg",$binary);
    // you can echo the URL, and return it to your API or show on web
    echo url("storage/img/some-image.jpg"); 
    // or you can write to DB
    // Example Model, change to anything
    $imgTable =  new TableImage();
    $imgTable->url = url("storage/img/some-image.jpg");
    $imgTable->save();
}
```

You can use `Log` facade to log the result of the saving image.
Hope this help, and if it help you, please set it as acceptable answer. thanks.